# Django Querysets - Using .annotate() after .extra()

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Let us say I have a very simple model like this one:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(unique=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Basically, I want to use Django's ORM API to get the average duration per category. The SQL query will look something like this:

```
SELECT category, AVG(end_time - start_time) AS avg_duration
FROM test_table
GROUP BY category
```

I tried using the following code, but according to the docs, F() expressions in .annotate() is only available in Djano 1.8.

```
Test.objects.values('category', 'start_time', 'end_time').annotate(avg_duration=Avg(F(end_time) - F(start_time))
```

I also tried using .extra() like this, but I get a FieldError.

```
Test.objects.extra(select={'duration':'end_time - start_time'}).values('category', 'duration').annotate(avg_duration=Avg('duration'))
```

From the looks of things, the 2nd attempt suggests that the annotate function cannot resolve column aliases. Is this really the case, or am I missing something?

Furthermore, short of creating an additional column that stores derived information (duration per entry), using Django 1.8, and/or using raw SQL, what other alternatives can you guys recommend? Any help will very much be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Test.objects.values('category').extra(select={'avg_duration':'AVG(end_time - start_time)'})
```

Yep, it won't happen, because

> Any extra() call made after a values() call will have its extra selected fields ignored.

You can't use it before `.values()` either, because you will be forced to include it into the `.values()`:

> If you use a values() clause after an extra() call, any fields defined by a select argument in the extra() must be explicitly included in the values() call.

so this way any `.extra` select will be included [in the grouping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

But you can't also make such kind of `Avg` without `.extra` so i think the only solution which had left is to use [`.raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries)

```
Test.objects.raw('\
    SELECT id, category, AVG(end_time - start_time) AS avg_duration \
    FROM test_table \
    GROUP BY category'
)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and also tried this one fearing that the required columns for .extra() might not be detected.
`Test.objects.values('category', 'end_time', 'start_time').extra(select={'avg_duration':'AVG(end_time - start_time)'})`

The results I got was similar to a basic select query like this:
`SELECT category, end_time, start_time FROM test_table`

Nice suggestion, but I think this is why it did not work:
"Any extra() call made after a values() call will have its extra selected fields ignored."
From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values)

Comment: Yep you are right. I played for a while with the shell testing different variations but cant find a solution different from `.raw` ;(

Comment: I really appreciate the suggestions and the effort! I will be marking this as answered for the benefit of others using Django 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django 1.8 or higher, you could use something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, F

Test.objects.annotate(avg_duration=Avg(F('end_time') - F('start_time')))
```